# static lifetime

Tags: c

I have a problem regarding static variables. It is said that the life of the static variable is beyond the bounds of the function (if defined in a function). But a pointer to it must give the value if it exits. But it does not work.

```
#include<stdio.h>
int *p;
int main()
{
    clrscr();
    test();
    printf("%d",*p);
    return 0;
}

void test(void)
{
    static int chacha=0;
    p=&chacha;
}
```

Comment: Now that you modified the code to declare `p` global and assign it to `&chacha`, does it still not work?

Comment: Then I suggest reverting the code you posted to the original so that future readers of the question and answer can understand the problem and its solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It doesn't look like you declared `p` anywhere.

Try this in `test`:

```
int* test(void)
{
    static int chacha = 0;
    return &chacha;
}
```

Now if your main is:

```
int main()
{
    int *p;
    clrscr();
    p = test();
    printf("%d",*p);
    getch();
    return 0;
}
```

you'll see the behavior you expect.

Answer (score 2):

```
int *p;

int main()
. . .
. . .
. . .
p = &chacha;
```